# For Google Search Console, Will data still be intact when using a different domain verification?

Tags: google-search-console, statistics, reporting, site-verification

Per what's discussed in this article:

https://saradoesseo.com/seo-basics/set-up-google-search-console/

I'd like to switch the sites we set up with the URL prefix verifcation over to the Domain verifcation for a more complete data collection.

In my head the process would be:

- Remove `http://example.com`
- Remove `https://example.com`
- Add `example.com` + update txt record for domain verification.

My concern is data loss from removing the URL prefix added properties.

Will the data we collected with the URL prefixed sites still be intact when it's added via the Domain Verification?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no data loss, but the new domain property may take a while to populate.

Note that some integrations do not support domain properties yet. Like linking to Google Analytics.

I'd not delete any site level properties. Keep them as a backup. Even consider adding the www variants.

Comment: Sounds good Tony! It's not a problem to keep the other properties as a backup.

Comment: No. Think of each property as a different view of the data.